# Trying to replace image in database PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem. I'm trying to create a system where images can be replaced and then it will change in the database. However my article_pictures is made up like this "image1&image2&image2" so I wanted the system to check if one specific image has been changed and upload that one and change the name on that string.

though it uploads the pictures anyway the string is replaced by nothing ("") instead of changing a value

Now I created the following code and I really hope someone gets what is wrong

```
if (isset($_POST['updateArticle']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $article = $_POST['article'];       
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
    $max_file_size = 1024*1000; //1000 kb
    $count = 0;

    $articleid = $_GET['edit'];
    $collectarticle = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE article_id = '$articleid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $collectarticle);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $pictcount = $row[article_picturecount];
            $pictcount2 = 0;
            do
            {
                $picturename[$pictcount2] = $_FILES['edit_'.$count2];
                $pictcount = $count - 1;
                $pictcount2++;
            }
            while($pictcount > 0);

            $pictures = explode('&' , $row[article_pictures]);
            $count = $row[article_picturecount];
            $count2 = 0;
            do 
            {
                if ($picturename[$count2] != "")
                {
                    if ($pictures[$count2] != $picturename[$count2]['name'])
                    {
                        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["edit".$count2]["tmp_name"],"../img/uploads/".$picturename[$count2]))
                        {
                            $pictures[$count2] = $picturename[$count2];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Er is iets misgegaan met het uploaden van picturename[".$count2."]";
                            die();
                        }
                    }
                }
                $count = $count - 1;
                $count2++;
            }
            while($count > 0);

            $count = $row[article_picturecount];
            $pictcount2 = 0;
            $andcount = $row[article_picturecount] - 1;

            do
            {
                $picturenameupdate = $pictures[$count2];
                if ($andcount > 0)
                {
                    $picturenameupdate = $picturenameupdate."&";
                    $andcount = $andcount - 1;
                }
                $count = $count - 1;
                $count2++;
            }
            while($count > 0);
        }
    }

    $articleid = $_GET['edit'];
    $database = "UPDATE ARTICLES SET article_title = '$title', article_content = '$article', article_pictures = '$picturenameupdate' WHERE article_id = '$articleid'";
    if (mysqli_query($con,$database))
    {
        $notice = "Het artikel is aangepast!";
        header('Location: http://portal.globaltowerservices.nl?notice='.$notice);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $notice = "Er is iets mis gegaan. Probeer het opnieuw.";
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to normalize your database. storing multiple pieces of data in a single field is invariably a sign of a bad design, ESPECIALLY if you then start needing to deal with smaller parts of that "blob" of data.

Comment: I use it because I do not limit the amount of pictures that can be added so I cannot predict how many fields I need in the database so this is the way I cope with that

Comment: that's irrelevant. a properly normalized database would put those multi-values into a  child table, and then you can trivially restrict how many of those child records there are for every parent record.

Comment: I can somewhat think of what you mean, have only been doing this for 4 months so I did what I knew. I'll at least take that with me when I need to do something similair. Thanks.

Comment: Lucas, you would have a table of your data, with a Primary Key, and then another table with your image informartion, where you can CRUD image rows into that simple table, and then you would have a third table to form a relationship between these two, featuring its own PK column, as well as the PK col for the corresponding data-row and the PK of the image-row to be associated with that data-row, therefore you can then easily have as many or as few images associated with as many or as few data-rows as you want, simply by adding or removing rows from the *relationship* table.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be this:

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{ 
    if (isset($_POST['updateArticle']))
    {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $article = $_POST['article'];

    $articleid = $_GET['edit'];
    $collectarticle = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE article_id = '$articleid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $collectarticle);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if ($row[article_picturecount] > 1)
            {
                $pictcount = $row[article_picturecount];
                $pictcount2 = 0;
                do
                {
                    $name = "edit_".$pictcount2;
                    $picturename[$pictcount2] = $_FILES[$name]['name'];
                    $pictcount = $pictcount - 1;
                    $pictcount2++;
                }
                while($pictcount > 0);
            }
            else
            {
                $picturename = $_FILES['edit_1']['name'];
            }
            if ($row[article_picturecount] > 1)
            {
                $pictures = explode('&' , $row[article_pictures]);
            }
            else
            {
                $pictures = $row[article_pictures];
            }
            if ($row[article_picturecount] > 1)
            {
                $uploadcount = $row[article_picturecount];
                $uploadcount2 = 0;
                do 
                {
                    if ($picturename[$uploadcount2] != "")
                    {
                        if ($pictures[$uploadcount2] != $picturename[$uploadcount2]['name'])
                        {
                            $name = "edit_".$uploadcount2;
                            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"],"../img/uploads/".$picturename[$uploadcount2]))
                            {
                                $pictures[$uploadcount2] = $_FILES[$name]['name'];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo "lol nee";
                                die();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $uploadcount = $uploadcount - 1;
                    $uploadcount2++;
                }
                while($uploadcount > 0);
            }
            else
            {
                if($pictures != $picturename)
                {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['edit_1']["tmp_name"],"../img/uploads/".$picturename))
                    {
                        $pictures = $picturename;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "het uploaden is niet gelukt";
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($row[article_picturecount] > 1)
            {
                $count = $row[article_picturecount];
                $count2 = 0;
                $andcount = $row[article_picturecount] - 1;
                $picturenameupdate = "";
                do
                {
                    if ($picturenameupdate == "")
                    {
                        $picturenameupdate = $pictures[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $picturenameupdate = $picturenameupdate.$pictures[$count2];
                    }
                    if ($andcount > 0)
                    {
                        $picturenameupdate = $picturenameupdate."&";
                        $andcount = $andcount - 1;
                    }
                    $count = $count - 1;
                    $count2++;
                }
                while($count > 0);
            }
            else
            {
                $picturenameupdate = $pictures;
            }
        }
    }

    $articleid = $_GET['edit'];
    $database = "UPDATE ARTICLES SET article_title = '$title', article_content = '$article', article_pictures = '$picturenameupdate' WHERE article_id = '$articleid'";
    if (mysqli_query($con,$database))
    {
        $notice = "Het artikel is aangepast!";
        header('Location: http://portal.globaltowerservices.nl?notice='.$notice);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $notice = "Er is iets mis gegaan. Probeer het opnieuw.";
    }

}
?>
```

This also covers articles with only one image